# Remote Desktop across internet to AzureAD machine

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services

I am trying to connect to another computer using remote desktop. Both are physical computers connected to our work account (office 365). Both device are joined to the same AzureAD tenant.

They both have NLA turned off.

They both have had the same user sign into them, and they both have that user in there remote users group.

When I try to connect with:

Computer: WORKSTATIONNAME

User: AzureAD\user@contoso.com

I always get computer can not be found.

Note that these devices are in different locations and behind different modems/LANS.

They are both on premise clients but behind seperate LANs.

Comment: What OS is on this machine?

Comment: It makes sense that the computer can't be found unless you connect to a DNS FQDN that's publicly resolvable. Try connecting to the public ip address instead.

Comment: @joeqwerty I would assume public IP address would first involve opening ports on the modem - not great from security perspective. I had hoped that by having them on the same "cloud" domain would enable connection. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: They're not in the same "cloud" domain. They're joined to Azure AD but they don't "live" in Azure AD.

Comment: Are computers in the same local network through VPN for example? Can the first workstation reach the second one by ICMP ping?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Where are these machines, are they on premises or in Azure? Can you resolve them using DNS from the command line?

Comment: Updated. But they are on premise, seperate LANs. I had hoped that RDP would work by virtue of same AzureAD   but appears not.

Answer (score 1):

All Azure AD is providing here is the authentication for your machines, that is it. It is not providing any means for them to resolve each other, and it is not providing network connectivity for them to be able to talk to each other, it's purely an authentication mechanism.

If you want to be able to RDP between the machines you would need to:

1. Either create a way to resolve the machines by name (DNS Server, Host Records etc.) or connect using IP address
2. Configure a way for network connectivity between the two, either through exposing ports in your routers, some sort of VPN connection or similar